# Osmdroid map crushes in Android 10

Tags: osmdroid

The targetsdk is 30 and it only crushes when it's used in android version 10. It is happening because of the cache directory isn't implemented as previously.
The github issue holds the following code-

```
IConfigurationProvider configuration = Configuration.getInstance();
File path = context.getFilesDir();
File osmdroidBasePath = new File(path, "osmdroid");
osmdroidBasePath.mkdirs();
File osmdroidTilePath = new File(osmdroidBasePath, "tiles");
osmdroidTilePath.mkdirs();
configuration.setOsmdroidBasePath(osmdroidBasePath);
configuration.setOsmdroidTileCache(osmdroidTileCache);
```

Didn't understand how to initiate osmdroidTileCache

Comment: Have you got the log from the crash?

Comment: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference"      Sorry, I have fixed the problem. Thanks a lot for mentioning.